# Python nested loop, break if conditions not satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, loops, break

I have been trying to use a nested loop to iterate through the rows of a pandas DataFrame, the outer loop, and for each row check if the conditions of a rule, a list of tuples:[(Attribute,Value),(Att,Val)], match those Att,Val pairs in the row of the DataFrame, the inner loop. If all conditions in the rule are satisfied I wish to record the index of the row, if 1 or more conditions fail I wish to break out of the inner loop without recording the row index and continue to the next row.

I have tried placing the break statement in the inner loop, the outer loop etc but I cannot get it to work as I wish. Many thanks for any attempts at helping me.

```
def rule_coverage(self, rule):

    for index,row in self.data.iterrows():  

        for selector in rule:

            if row[selector[0]]  != selector[1]:
                break

        coverage.append(index)

 return self.data.iloc[coverage]
```

Comment: This is an inefficient way to iterate over a dataframe. Show your data, and explain what you are trying to do, and we can provide you with a vectorized approach that should be much faster than this.

Comment: I am currently using a simple dataset with 5 attributes and integer values for each, the rules may test a single or multiple attributes. I hope to expand the code to deal with more complex data, missing data etc but am currently trying to get a working version on the lense data set from UCI [link](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/lenses). Could I still use vectorised operations if different rules tested different numbers of attributes?

Comment: I asked for your data... not an explanation... we can't understand what you want without data or expected output.

Comment: The [data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/lenses/lenses.data) . The first column is just a row index and the last column is the class label, the columns between are the attributes.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. What is your expected output for this sample data?

Comment: I am currently testing a rule which mandates that the first 2 attributes should both equal 1 which means that only the first 4 rows of the data satisfy it. I want my code to record the index of these 4 rows, in the _coverage_ variable and thereafter activate the break statement and not record the index of the subsequent rows. Currently my code does activate the break statement for rows 5-24 but it still appends the index of those rows to _coverage_.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

Let `s` be a `pandas.Series` that represents the `rule`

```
s = pd.Series(dict(rule))
```

Reassign the dataframe to be aligned with `s`

```
d, s = self.data.align(s, 'inner', 1)
```

Then compare and return only where true for the entire row

```
self.data[d.eq(s).all(1)]
```

Comment: The rules may test any number of the attributes of a given data point and each rule may test a different number of attributes, could your suggested approach accomodate this?

Comment: @seanysull this is the point of providing a minimal and complete verifiable example. Without it, I can’t be certain what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Comrades, I managed to solve the problem myself by following the advice of many other posts that suggested refactoring the inner loop as a function which returns the desired result to the outer loop. Thanks for all advice given. The solution is below, the upper function is the former inner loop while the lower function is the now simplified outer loop.

```
def check_rule_datapoint(self, datapoint, complex):
    """
    Function to check if a given data point satisfies
    the conditions of a given complex. Data point 
    should be a pandas Series. Complex should be a
    tuple or a list of tuples where each tuple is of
    the form ('Attribute', 'Value').
    """
    if type(complex) == tuple:
        if datapoint[complex[0]] == complex[1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    if type(complex) == list:
        result = True   
        for selector in complex:
            if datapoint[selector[0]] != selector[1]:
                result = False

        return result       

def complex_coverage(self, complex):
    """ Returns set of instances of the data 
        which complex(rule) covers.
    """

    #import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace(context=8)
    coverage = []

    #iterate over dataframe rows
    for index,row in self.data.iterrows():
        if self.check_rule_datapoint(row, complex):
            coverage.append(index)

    return self.data.iloc[coverage]
```